# Issue in creating ODATA Filter URL

Tags: sharepoint-2010, odata

I am trying to apply A & (B & C) operation in and ODATA url But it is not working as expected. Anyone please help us to solve my issue. I am providing my request url for your reference

**https://xyz.abcd.com/company/events/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MasterCalendar?$filter=CommunicationTypeValue eq 'Company Holiday' and (StartDate gt 
DateTime'2015-12-10T09:13:28' and StartDate lt datetime'2015-12 16T03:30:00.000')**

But when I try to run it as individual queries it is working fine

like

**https://xyz.abcd.com/company/events/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MasterCalendar?$filter=CommunicationTypeValue eq 'Company Holiday'**

**https://xyz.abcd.com/company/events/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MasterCalendar?$filter= StartDate gt DateTime'2015-12-10T09:13:28' and StartDate lt datetime'2015-12-16T03:30:00.000'**

But when i try to combine these two issue starts.

Anyone please help me to solve this issue

Comment: What's the error message? Did you try to remove the parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can apply filter using separate **"AND"** condition; Something similar to this,

**MasterCalendar?$filter=(CommunicationTypeValue eq 'Company Holiday') and (StartDateTime ge datetime'2015-01-01') and (StartDateTime le datetime'2015-12-15')**

Also you can use select case if needed for getting the specific dates.